# How do I delete a block a text using the mouse cursor?

Tags: key-bindings

Yes, I know this is unconventional, but I just want to know.

When I right click on a chunk of higlighted text, the  dropdown doesn't show any option for deleting - just `copy`, `copy as html`...`show menu bar`

I want the option for **deleting** a chunk of text as well: How do I accomplish this?

(bracing myself for the "that's not how you use vim" shaming)

Comment: what OS/platform, and gvim or vim?

Comment: `:he popup-menu`

Comment: In most Guis, selecting chunks is the same as visual mode, and therefore, you press `x` or `d` to delete, `y` to copy.

Comment: In gvim 8.1 on Windows, this option is already shown.